# Code duplication for functions that take shared_ptr and unique_ptr

Tags: c++11, parameters, smart-pointers, code-duplication

Problem:

Let's assume I have an algorithm that takes a unique_ptr to some type:

```
void FancyAlgo(unique_ptr<SomeType>& ptr);
```

Now I have shared_ptr sPtr to SomeType, and I need to apply the same algorithm on sPtr. Does this mean I have to duplicate the algorithm just for the shared_ptr?

```
void FancyAlgo(shared_ptr<SomeType>& sPtr);
```

I know smart pointers come with ownership of the underlying managed object on the heap. Here in my FancyAlgo, ownership is usually not an issue. I thought about stripping off the smart pointer layer and do something like:

```
void FancyAlgo(SomeType& value);
```

and when I need to call it with unique_ptr:

```
FancyAlgo(*ptr);
```

likewise for shared_ptr.

1, Is this an acceptable style in PRODUCTION code?(I saw somewhere that in a context of smart pointers, you should NOT manipulate raw pointers in a similar way. It has the danger of introducing mysterious bugs.)

2, Can you suggest any better way (without code duplication) if 1 is not a good idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Smart pointers should almost never be passed by reference, unless you want to talk about the smart pointer itself, not the pointee. Use `.get()` or `*`.

Comment: Why not? In the old C++03 it was perfectly fine to pass pointers around. Now it's just become pointers with ownership. I don't see why it has an impact on your decision.

Comment: Because usually the pointer isn't the object of interest, but the pointee is.

Comment: If you are simply mutating the object passed in, you don't need to bother with smart-pointers - simply work with a reference. If the argument could potentially be empty or invalid, consider using something like `boost::optional` to hold this information, as opposed the old practice of using pointer nullness as the indicator.

Comment: Yeah. Passing in the pointee solves the problem. However, in the sole context of the function(assume a different developer implements this function), there's nothing at all to hint the implementation developer that he should not manage the pointee with another smart pointer(e.g. shared_ptr<SomeType> another_ptr (&value);). If he does this then we'll have double deletion problem later. If the function signature has a smart pointer, then it's a clear sign that he should not try to manage the object with another smart pointer.

Comment: Also, do you think it's always better to exclude pointers(whether smart or raw) from function signatures? Why and why not?(I've always had the impression that it's perfectly fine to pass in pointers; anyway, I saw lots of functions having reference in their signatures, which is essentially pointers; also, for pass by value, copy elision may not have extra overhead in certain cases, but there're always cases where it can not optimize.)

Answer (score 2):

Smart pointers are about ownership.  Asking for a smart pointer is asking for ownership information or control.

Asking for a non-const lvalue reference to a smart pointer is asking for permission to change the ownership status of that value.

Asking for a const lvalue reference to a smart pointer is asking for permission to query the ownership status of that value.

Asking for an rvalue reference to a smart pointer is being a "sink", and promising to take that ownership away from the caller.

Asking for a const rvalue reference is a bad idea.

If you are accessing the *pointed to* value, and you want it to be non-nullable, a reference to the underlying type is good.

If you want it to be nullable, a `boost::optional<T&>` or a `T*` are acceptable, as is the `std::experimental` "world's dumbest smart pointer" (or an equivalent hand-written one).  All of these are non-owning nullable references to some variable.

In an interface, don't ask for things you don't need and won't need in the future.  That makes reasoning about what the function does harder, and leads to problems like you have in the OP.  A function that reseats a reference is a very different function from one that reads a value.

---

Now, a more interesting question based off yours is one where you *want* the function to reseat the smart pointer, but you want to be able to do it to both shared and unique pointer inputs.  This is sort of a strange case, but I could imagine writing a type-erase-down-to-emplace type (a `emplace_sink<T>`).

```
template<class T>
using later_ctor = std::function<T*(void*)>;

template<class T, class...Args>
later_ctor<T> delayed_emplace(Args&&...args) {
  // relies on C++1z lambda reference reference binding, write manually
  // if that doesn't get in, or don't want to rely on it:
  return [&](void* ptr)->T* {
    return new T(ptr)(std::forward<Args>(args));
  };
}

namespace details {
  template<class T>
  struct emplace_target {
    virtual ~emplace_target() {}
    virtual T* emplace( later_ctor<T> ctor ) = 0;
  };
}
template<class T>
struct emplacer {
  std::unique_ptr<emplace_target<T>> pImpl;
  template<class...Args>
  T* emplace( Args&&... args ) {
    return pImpl->emplace( delayed_emplace<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
  }
  template<class D>
  emplacer( std::shared_ptr<T, D>& target ):
    pImpl( new details::emplace_shared_ptr<T,D>(&target) ) // TODO
  {}
  template<class D>
  emplacer( std::unique_ptr<T, D>& target ):
    pImpl( new details::emplace_unique_ptr<T,D>(&target) ) // TODO
  {}
};
```

etc.  Lots of polish needed.  The idea is to type-erase construction of an object `T` into an arbitrary context.  We might need to special case `shared_ptr` so we can call `make_shared`, as a `void*->T*` delayed ctor is not good enough to pull that off (not fundamentally, but because of lack of API hooks).

Aha!  I can do a make shared shared ptr without special casing it much.

We allocate a block of memory (`char[sizeof(T)]`) with a destructor that converts the buffer to `T` then calls delete, in-place construct in that buffer (getting the `T*`), then convert to a `shared_ptr<T>` via the `shared_ptr<T>( shared_ptr<char[sizeof(T)]>, T* )` constructor.  With careful exception catching this should be safe, and we can emplace using our emplacement function into a `make_shared` combined buffer.

Comment: For the first part, I left two comments under the OP for extended discussion on the ambiguity of ownership and the potential double deletion problem led from there. For the second part, the emplacer is insane, but I like it :p Why do I need an emplacer like this? My understanding is you're trying to implement the virtual constructor mechanism(and set it as the context for the shared_ptr/unique_ptr discussion), but in which situation would it be necessary and helpful?

Comment: @h9uest Yes, a `T*` has ambiguous ownership.  Hence [N3840](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf), the Worlds Dumbest Smart Pointer -- `std::experimental::observer_ptr` -- which states "I do not own what I point to", and otherwise behaves as much like `T*` as possible. A `T&` is a non-nullable non-reseatable `T*` that conventionally does *not* own what it refers to and which has reference semantics and cannot have "its" address taken nor its "bits" written (or really read) in any standards-compliant way, thereby making certain optimizations easier for the compiler.

Comment: @h9uest as for the second, if you wanted a function that produce both a `unique_ptr<T>` or `shared_ptr<T>`, the `emplacer<T>` could erase the difference.  Then you would need one implementation, and that implementation can be inside a `.cpp` file instead of template exposed in the header.  An alternative to `emplacer<T>` is a `std::function<void(T&&)>` -- a value-sink -- but that requires your `T` be movable (ideally efficiently). The emplacer<T> is basically a "stronger" value-sink that supports more types and is more efficient. value-sinks/emplacers can be used in place of output iterators.